# Universal revert to iphone only

Tags: xcode5

Apple rejected my app because is Universal and I do not prepare for iPad, only for iPhone. 
it is largely discussed but the replies does not work for me.

- Select Project Navigator
- Select your project file
- Make sure your project file is selected and not a target
- Select the Build Settings tab
- Scroll Down to deployment section and search through that for "Targeted Device Family" or search that key term in the search field at the top
- Change iphone/ipad to iPhone only

Already changed in the Deployment Info to Main interface to Main_iPhone e Devices to iPhone only

- Still have 2 targets, `iOSSDK7.1`
- Still have `main_ipad.Storyboard`
- when RUN still run for universal.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine as long as you only select iPhone under Devices. It does not matter that you have iPad capable files in your bundle (such as an iPad specific storyboard), nor does it matter that you have an iPad target - as long as you have one for iPhone only. What you change under "Devices" is in fact the target. As long as it looks like this you're OK:

[image]

The easiest way to test this is to run you iPhone app on an iPad or iPad simulator. If you see that it's running in iPhone compatibility mode, your app is iPhone only.